# git merge into master branch uncommitable

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, gerrit

I am still new to git so please forgive me if this has been asked before, I have not been able to find a solution. I am using git and gerrit and am trying to merge a branch `issue` into the `master` branch however, when I do it doesn't seem to commit/push to the remote repository. NOTE: it does seem to merge successfully locally without any conflicts. I am trying to merge the latest pushed commits in each branch.

So, this is what I have done:

1) switch to the master branch. 2) in the Eclipse GUI and using the git bash shell ran `git merge issue` 3) `git status` > 2 commits above remote repo 4) `git pull` > no new changes 5) `git commit` > no new changes 6) `git push` > remote rejected, no new changes.

All changes are commited and pushed in each branch, I am only trying to merge the changes in `issue` into `master`. When I do a `git merge` from the git bash shell, it seems to get hung up for at least 15 min, which it should take 2 if gerrit is heavily loaded at the time. No matter what I do, after I merge the branches, it tells me I am above by 2 commits, but every command I know of will say I don't have anything to change. Included commands: pull, push, commit, rebase (--soft and --mixed), reset, etc. The only thing that I have found that will show a difference is if I do a `git log` it will show the commits from the merge, and `git log master` does not have the commits.

I have wiped my local repository and re-created it several times to see if there was something I messed up. Each time I get this issue. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
**git status results:**

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**git push bash shell:**

```
$ git push
*
```

NOTE: on a git push the * is not actually there but where it has a `|` just blinking, which is where it seems to get hung up.

**EDIT 3:** The same push is still hung up, 1 hour later.

**EDIT 2:**
**git remote bash shell:**

```
$ git remote -v show
origin  ssh://sparks@gerrit:PORT/PROJECT (fetch)
origin  ssh://sparks@gerrit:PORT/PROJECT (push)
```

Neither Eclipse nor my git bash actively have any activity with git right now other than the `git push`

Comment: Please include the actual output of `git status` and the actual error from `git push`

Comment: added the ouput, see edit.

Comment: hmm, how about `git remote -v show`.  It looks like something isn't going right when you push.

Comment: see 2nd edit please.

Comment: Have you verified your SSH setup and connectivity? (I unfortunately don't have any suggestions as to what the exact steps are here)

Comment: Yes, gerrit has a functionality that allows you to just copy-paste the ssh string. I imported and set up the connectivity to the remote repo using that string provided by gerrit.

Comment: I'm guessing that the merge from the issue branch was a fast-forward merge that didn't produce a commit that Gerrit didn't already know about. To force the creation of a merge commit (which will end up as a reviewable change in Gerrit), pass `--no-ff` to `git merge`.

Comment: @MagnusBäck that seems to have been the solution, if you want to submit an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge from the issue branch was a fast-forward merge, i.e. a merge that only advances the branch pointer of the target branch (the one you have checked out) and doesn't produce any new commits.

Unless you add additional options to the push Gerrit refuses to accept changes pushed to refs/for/branchname if the commit SHA-1 is known, i.e. it isn't a new commit. In your case the contents of the issue branch had been pushed to Gerrit before.

To force the creation of a merge commit pass `--no-ff` to `git merge`. That merge commit will end up as a reviewable change in Gerrit.